# Azure DevOps Server 2020 and http/2

Tags: http2, iis-10, azure-devops-server

I've set up http**s** on our Azure DevOps Server 2020.0.1 and want IIS to serve the website over http/2. When browsing the website with a Chromium based browser (Chrome, Edge) all content is served over http/1.1. When browsing with Firefox static content of the website is served over http/2 and api generated content is served over http/1.1.

I want that all content in all mentioned browsers is served over http/2. Is that possible?

OS is Windows Server 2016.

Answer (score 1):

Not all IIS features are enabled for HTTP/2, so sometimes your browser can only connect via HTTP 1.1. Microsoft documents the scenarios in [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-10/http2-on-iis#when-is-http2-not-supported),

> ### When is HTTP/2 Not Supported?
>
> In a few cases, HTTP/2 can't be used in combination with other features. In these situations, Windows will
> fall back to HTTP/1.1 and continue the transaction. This may involve
> negotiating HTTP/1.1 during the handshake, or sending an error code to
> the client instructing it to retry over an HTTP/1.1 connection.
>
> - Windows authentication (NTLM/Kerberos/Negotiate) is not supported with HTTP/2. In this case IIS will fall back to HTTP/1.1.
> - Clear text - as mentioned above, IIS currently only supports HTTP/2 over TLS. Again, IIS will fall back to HTTP/1.1.
> - Bandwidth throttling - IIS has a feature to limit bandwidth (in Inetmgr, select the site, 'Limits' under Configure of the Action
>   pane). This applies to HTTP/1.1 but is not enforced for HTTP/2 (will
>   proceed with no errors or bandwidth limiting).

Comment: so maybe Windows authentication is the reason why some parts of Azure DevOps Server are served over HTTP/1.1

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have found on my "why is chrome using http/1.1 quest".
It appears to be a known bug, that chromium falls back to http/1.1.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=832586